# Connect Rails Puma Application Server to SSL protected Web Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, puma

I want to enable SSL on RAILS 5 applicaton.

Therefore I installed NGINX and created a server block for this web server.

```
server {

# SSL configuration
#
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.domain/chain.pem;
```

I want to connect together the already existing PUMA application server and the newley running SSL enabled NGINX Web Server. On the internet I find only quite expired guides HOW-TO-DO.

I'm looking for a current guide that can be followed.

E.g. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-https-with-ruby-on-rails is good but it also does not explain how to connect. It keeps the NGINX SSL enabled Web Server alone.

Comment: Side-Note: Is the Nginx exposed to the internet? If **not**, puma can offer SSL support (much like iodine)?

Comment: You're looking to [set up Nginx as a reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). There are plenty of [tutorials](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-reverse-proxy). Find one you like... Good Luck!